# How can I format a json date in dd/mm/yy format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, datetime-format

I have a json date like `\/Date(1334514600000)\/` in my response and when I convert it in javascript then I got this date `Tue Apr 17 2012 11:37:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`, 
but I need the date format like `17/04/2012` and I fail every time. Can anyone tell me how can I resolve it?

Comment: There are already many answers for this on stack overflow.

Comment: i was checked most of the answer but none the working for me :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think that the other posted answers are quite right, you have already accepted one as working for you so I won't edit it.

Here is an updated version of your accepted answer.

```
var dateString = "\/Date(1334514600000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString ));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
alert(date);
```

It uses a technique from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/79835) to extract the epoch from the JSON date.

Comment: You can also use `var date = new Date(+dateString.match(/\d+/)[0]);` to convert the time to a date. Be careful though as the date object will be in the timezone of the system where the code is executed.

Comment: This gives me 2/1/2019. how do I get 02/01/2019?

Comment: Replying to KMR question
==============================================================================================================
var dateString = "\/Date(1334514600000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
var month = ("0" + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + currentTime.getDate()).slice(-2);
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
alert(date);

Answer (score 1):

I found very helpful the row1 answer, however i got stuck on the format for input type="date" as only returns one string for decimals under 10, I was able to modify to work on input type="date", I basically adapted the code from row1 to the code from the link http://venkatbaggu.com/convert-json-date-to-date-format-in-jquery/

I was able through jquery .val add the date to the input

```
var dateString = "\/Date(1334514600000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
var month = ("0" + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + currentTime.getDate()).slice(-2);
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of your accepted answer. DD/MM/YYYY Format Get Try This..

```
var dateString = "/Date(1623781800000+0530)/"+.substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
 if (month.toString().length == 1) 
   month = "0" + month.toString();
 if (day.toString().length == 1){ 
   day = "0" + currentTime.getDate();}                                       
var datenew = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
alert(date);
```

Comment: I'm trying this but it is not working
<input type="hidden" value="\/Date(1334514600000)\/" />

var currentTime = new Date($("input").val());
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
alert(date);

Answer (score 0):

It's answer to your question...

Build the date object with your timestamp

```
var currentTime = new Date(1334514600000)
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
alert(date);​
```

it works

http://jsfiddle.net/ChgUa/

Comment: You are missing the step where you convert `\/Date(1334514600000)\/` to `new Date(1334514600000)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//parse JSON formatted date to javascript date object
var bdate = new Date(parseInt(emp.Birthdate.substr(6)));

//format display date (e.g. 04/10/2012)
var displayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", bdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of formatting date is by using pipes if you are using Angular.
Click [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
//in .ts file
ngOnInit() {
 this.currentDate = new Date()
}
//in html file
<p>Current date is:</p>{{currentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

//Output: 22/04/2020
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var Date = new Date(Tue Jun 15 2021 23:52:47 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)).toDateString(); console.log(Date);
```

---

Result == Tue Jun 15 2021

---

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Also, this is syntactically invalid, you need to surround the `Tue Jun 15...` with quotes.